# Getting data from JSON GraphQL Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, functional-programming, gatsby

I'm trying to get some data from a GraphQL query, but i'm having some trouble.

When i try to map over some JSon data, i can't get data from the arrays inside the data.

I'm not sure what i'm missing.

What i've tried:

1. This works fine:

```js
<div>
      {data.allDataJson.nodes.map(listing => (
          <div>
            <h2>{listing.name}</h2> 
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

but when i try to get the Camere array, i can't access the data.

2. When i do: it gives me the error

```js
{data.allDataJson.nodes.map(listing => (
          <div>
            <h2>{listing.name}</h2>
            <h2>{listing.camere}</h2>
          </div>
))}
```

- Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, amount}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

  3. also this:

```js
<div>
      {data.allDataJson.nodes.map(listing => (
          <div>
            <h2>{listing.name}</h2>

            {listing.camere.map(
              camere => 
              <div>
                <h1>{camere.name}</h1>
                <h1>{camere.amount}</h1>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

When i try to do .map on it like on an array, i get the error in the post title.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

const Listing = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query ListingQuery {
    allDataJson {
      nodes {
        camere {
          name
          amount
        }
        name
      }
    }
  }

`);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.allDataJson.nodes.map(listing => (
          <div>
            <h2>{listing.name}</h2>
            {listing.camere.map(home => <h1>{home.name}</h1>)}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Listing;
```

My data:

```
[ 
    { 
       "name":"Vila Franceza",
       "detaliipret":{ 
          "pret":"3000lei",
          "perioada":"iunie - iulie",
          "detaliu1":"Vila se inchiriaza exclusiv integral.",
          "detaliu2":"Vila se poate inchiria de persoane juridice sau de persoane fizice."
       },
       "detaliidescriere":[ 
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza este situată pe malul nordic al lacului Colibița, într-o poziție care asigură o perspectivă unică asupra lacului dar și a munților Călimani.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"La apă se ajunge prin intermediul debarcaderului situat la doar câțiva metri.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Accesul la vilă vă ferește de vizitatori nedoriți.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"În apropierea vilei există mai multe restaurante și păstrăvării.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Pentru amatorii de drumeții există trasee turistice pentru vizitarea împrejurimilor și a Munților Călimani. Zona este foarte darnică în privința ciupercilor de pădure.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Există, de asemenea, rute pentru amatorii de mountain bike.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Pentru a vă asigura discreția, liniștea și confortul de care aveți nevoie, nu se inchiriază camere individuale.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza asigura un spatiu de cazare ideal pentru 15 persoane.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza va ofera liniste, confort si discretie pentru o vacanta sau o luna de miere perfecta.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Constructia este moderna iar peretii de sticla permit iluminarea naturala in cea mai parte a zilei.  Lacul si crestele muntoase pot fi admirate cu usurinta, dar cu discretie, din interior.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Inchirierea vilei se poate face pentru orice perioada din cursul unei saptamani pentru minim două zile. Din respect pentru confortul dumneavoastră, Vila Franceză se inchiriază exclusiv integral.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"In interiorul vilei nu se fumeaza! Sunt admise animale de companie.",
             "type":"normal"
          }
       ],
       "camere":[ 
          { 
             "name":"Livingroom deschis",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Bucătărie americană",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Sală pentru servirea mesei",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Ieșire directă pe terasă",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Terasă deschisă pentru plajă, sport, cu loc acoperit pentru servirea mesei",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Dormitor cu jacuzzi",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Dormitor VIP cu jacuzzi și pat king size",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"dormitoare cu pat dublu",
             "amount":5
          },
          { 
             "name":"salon cu canapea extensibilă dublă",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Spațiu de joacă pentru copii",
             "amount":1
          }
       ],
       "dotari":[ 
          "TV satelit",
          "Wi-Fi",
          "Sistem de sonorizare stereo profesional",
          "Masa de biliard",
          "Joc fotbal de masa Babyfoot",
          "Doua caiace pentru amatorii de vaslit",
          "Saniute pentru sezonul de iarna",
          "Semineu cu lemne in living, cu scaune incalzite",
          "Incalzire centrala (electrica, pe lemne, pe gaz )",
          "Masina de spalat rufe",
          "Masina de uscat rufe",
          "Fier si masa de calcat",
          "Uscatoare de par",
          "Gril exterior XXL",
          "Disc pentru grătar",
          "Spa exterior cu apa ionizata, incalzi,ta, capacitate 10 persoane",
          "Sauna",
          "Debarcader privat pentru sporturi nautice",
          "Mobilier de plaja",
          "Parcare privată",
          "Sistem de supraveghere video",
          "Plita pe gaz",
          "Microunde",
          "Prajitor paine",
          "Taietor electric",
          "Robot de bucatarie",
          "Vesela si accesorii pentru 20 de persoane",
          "Masina de spalat vase",
          "Frigider dublu",
          "Cuptor pizza pentru 15 persoane. Se poate folosi si la patiserie, friptura etc",
          "Expresor și filtru cafea"
       ]
    },
    { 
       "name":"Casa Pescarilor",
       "detaliipret":{ 
          "pret":"800lei",
          "perioada":"iunie - iulie",
          "detaliu1":"Vila se inchiriaza exclusiv integral.",
          "detaliu2":"Vila se poate inchiria de persoane juridice sau de persoane fizice."
       },
       "detaliidescriere":[ 
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza este situată pe malul nordic al lacului Colibița, într-o poziție care asigură o perspectivă unică asupra lacului dar și a munților Călimani.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"La apă se ajunge prin intermediul debarcaderului situat la doar câțiva metri.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Accesul la vilă vă ferește de vizitatori nedoriți.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"În apropierea vilei există mai multe restaurante și păstrăvării.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Pentru amatorii de drumeții există trasee turistice pentru vizitarea împrejurimilor și a Munților Călimani. Zona este foarte darnică în privința ciupercilor de pădure.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Există, de asemenea, rute pentru amatorii de mountain bike.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Pentru a vă asigura discreția, liniștea și confortul de care aveți nevoie, nu se inchiriază camere individuale.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza asigura un spatiu de cazare ideal pentru 15 persoane.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza va ofera liniste, confort si discretie pentru o vacanta sau o luna de miere perfecta.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Constructia este moderna iar peretii de sticla permit iluminarea naturala in cea mai parte a zilei.  Lacul si crestele muntoase pot fi admirate cu usurinta, dar cu discretie, din interior.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Inchirierea vilei se poate face pentru orice perioada din cursul unei saptamani pentru minim două zile. Din respect pentru confortul dumneavoastră, Vila Franceză se inchiriază exclusiv integral.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"In interiorul vilei nu se fumeaza! Sunt admise animale de companie.",
             "type":"normal"
          }
       ],
       "camere":[ 
          { 
             "name":"Livingroom deschis",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Bucătărie americană",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Sală pentru servirea mesei",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Ieșire directă pe terasă",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Terasă deschisă pentru plajă, sport, cu loc acoperit pentru servirea mesei",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Dormitor cu jacuzzi",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Dormitor VIP cu jacuzzi și pat king size",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"dormitoare cu pat dublu",
             "amount":5
          },
          { 
             "name":"salon cu canapea extensibilă dublă",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Spațiu de joacă pentru copii",
             "amount":1
          }
       ],
       "dotari":[ 
          "TV satelit",
          "Wi-Fi",
          "Sistem de sonorizare stereo profesional",
          "Masa de biliard",
          "Joc fotbal de masa Babyfoot",
          "Doua caiace pentru amatorii de vaslit",
          "Saniute pentru sezonul de iarna",
          "Semineu cu lemne in living, cu scaune incalzite",
          "Incalzire centrala (electrica, pe lemne, pe gaz )",
          "Masina de spalat rufe",
          "Masina de uscat rufe",
          "Fier si masa de calcat",
          "Uscatoare de par",
          "Gril exterior XXL",
          "Disc pentru grătar",
          "Spa exterior cu apa ionizata, incalzi,ta, capacitate 10 persoane",
          "Sauna",
          "Debarcader privat pentru sporturi nautice",
          "Mobilier de plaja",
          "Parcare privată",
          "Sistem de supraveghere video",
          "Plita pe gaz",
          "Microunde",
          "Prajitor paine",
          "Taietor electric",
          "Robot de bucatarie",
          "Vesela si accesorii pentru 20 de persoane",
          "Masina de spalat vase",
          "Frigider dublu",
          "Cuptor pizza pentru 15 persoane. Se poate folosi si la patiserie, friptura etc",
          "Expresor și filtru cafea"
       ]
    },
    { 
       "name":"Modern Rooms Resort Colibita",
       "detaliipret":{ 
          "pret":"450lei",
          "perioada":"iunie - iulie",
          "detaliu1":"Vila se inchiriaza exclusiv integral.",
          "detaliu2":"Vila se poate inchiria de persoane juridice sau de persoane fizice."
       },
       "detaliidescriere":[ 
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza este situată pe malul nordic al lacului Colibița, într-o poziție care asigură o perspectivă unică asupra lacului dar și a munților Călimani.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"La apă se ajunge prin intermediul debarcaderului situat la doar câțiva metri.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Accesul la vilă vă ferește de vizitatori nedoriți.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"În apropierea vilei există mai multe restaurante și păstrăvării.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Pentru amatorii de drumeții există trasee turistice pentru vizitarea împrejurimilor și a Munților Călimani. Zona este foarte darnică în privința ciupercilor de pădure.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Există, de asemenea, rute pentru amatorii de mountain bike.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Pentru a vă asigura discreția, liniștea și confortul de care aveți nevoie, nu se inchiriază camere individuale.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza asigura un spatiu de cazare ideal pentru 15 persoane.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Vila Franceza va ofera liniste, confort si discretie pentru o vacanta sau o luna de miere perfecta.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Constructia este moderna iar peretii de sticla permit iluminarea naturala in cea mai parte a zilei.  Lacul si crestele muntoase pot fi admirate cu usurinta, dar cu discretie, din interior.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"Inchirierea vilei se poate face pentru orice perioada din cursul unei saptamani pentru minim două zile. Din respect pentru confortul dumneavoastră, Vila Franceză se inchiriază exclusiv integral.",
             "type":"normal"
          },
          { 
             "text":"In interiorul vilei nu se fumeaza! Sunt admise animale de companie.",
             "type":"normal"
          }
       ],
       "camere":[ 
          { 
             "name":"Livingroom deschis",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Bucătărie americană",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Sală pentru servirea mesei",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Ieșire directă pe terasă",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Terasă deschisă pentru plajă, sport, cu loc acoperit pentru servirea mesei",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Dormitor cu jacuzzi",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Dormitor VIP cu jacuzzi și pat king size",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"dormitoare cu pat dublu",
             "amount":5
          },
          { 
             "name":"salon cu canapea extensibilă dublă",
             "amount":1
          },
          { 
             "name":"Spațiu de joacă pentru copii",
             "amount":1
          }
       ],
       "dotari":[ 
          "TV satelit",
          "Wi-Fi",
          "Sistem de sonorizare stereo profesional",
          "Masa de biliard",
          "Joc fotbal de masa Babyfoot",
          "Doua caiace pentru amatorii de vaslit",
          "Saniute pentru sezonul de iarna",
          "Semineu cu lemne in living, cu scaune incalzite",
          "Incalzire centrala (electrica, pe lemne, pe gaz )",
          "Masina de spalat rufe",
          "Masina de uscat rufe",
          "Fier si masa de calcat",
          "Uscatoare de par",
          "Gril exterior XXL",
          "Disc pentru grătar",
          "Spa exterior cu apa ionizata, incalzi,ta, capacitate 10 persoane",
          "Sauna",
          "Debarcader privat pentru sporturi nautice",
          "Mobilier de plaja",
          "Parcare privată",
          "Sistem de supraveghere video",
          "Plita pe gaz",
          "Microunde",
          "Prajitor paine",
          "Taietor electric",
          "Robot de bucatarie",
          "Vesela si accesorii pentru 20 de persoane",
          "Masina de spalat vase",
          "Frigider dublu",
          "Cuptor pizza pentru 15 persoane. Se poate folosi si la patiserie, friptura etc",
          "Expresor și filtru cafea"
       ]
    }
 ]
```

What i want to be able to do:

Get all the details from all the data.

Comment: what error do you get when you try to map over camere ?

Comment: @ibtsam TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

For readability, add another function to extract `name`s for each `camere`.

```
const getNames = (camere) => (camere.map(home => <h1>{home.name}</h1>))

{data.allDataJson.nodes.map(listing => (
  <div>
    <h2>{listing.name}</h2>
    {
      listing.camere &&
      listing.camere.length > 0 &&
      this.getNames(listing.camere)
    }
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for that answer, it works.
Could you please explain why? What does this do?

 listing.camere &&
 listing.camere.length > 0 &&

Comment: @Link it's a conditional render. The names will only be shown if `listing.camere` is not null and it contains values.

Comment: Do you know why it didn't work before? just doing a map of camere inside the map of listing? Is it because some of them were null or something? I'm a little confused

Comment: Is it good practice to always do conditional render with data?

Comment: @Link it's good to minimize (or best eliminate) uncertainty. It's not good to always have conditional rendering. As this will only show there's too much stochacity inside the system. One rule is to know variables which will never be null. `null`ness can be captured through unit test.